# SQL Server - find values in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where i have to find the count of people in different age groups like:

```
0-5      12

6-10     35

11-15    26

16-20    57

20+      120
```

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server which will first create a temp table and store the age group like one column will have 0 and another will have 5 and so on. Then i'll loop through them and find the count between min and max range and will store the count with mim-max value in another temp table.

Is there any other easy and better way to achieve this output. Please advise.

Comment: Can you share with us the table structure associated with this data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps with `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT [0-5]   = SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 0 AND AGE <= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       [6-10]  = SUM(CASE WHEN AGE > 5 AND AGE <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       [11-15] = SUM(CASE WHEN AGE > 10 AND AGE <= 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       ....
FROM dbo.Persons
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6e39/6/0)

Or, with a range table you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `GROUP BY` + `COUNT`:

```
SELECT r.[From], r.[To], [Count]=COUNT(p.Age)
FROM dbo.Ranges r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Persons p
   ON p.[Age] >= r.[From] AND  p.[Age] <= r.[To]
GROUP BY r.[From], r.[To]
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19cf20/6/0)

Comment: Though I have created a seperate post for this question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355311/sql-server-simple-way-to-create-pivot
Can you suggest how to show the columns as rows. The first query works perfectly except that it creates column for every range. I would be having 100 ranges so i don't want them as separate columns but in a one columns as row values. 
Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: In this query after adding where clause it does not return all the range rows. Any idea why it is behaving like this,
SELECT r.[From], r.[To], [Sum]=SUM(p.Age) FROM dbo.Ranges r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Persons p ON p.[Age] >= r.[From] AND  p.[Age] <= r.[To]
where YMD BETWEEN '2013-05-03 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-05-03 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY r.[From], r.[To]
This returns only 1 row for which the data is available and not all the rows.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan is basically sound.

Having a range table with a min and max column is a good approach,

```
 AgeRange       MinAge      MaxAge
 5 and under    0           5
 6-10           6           10
 ...
```

but instead of "looping" you should try to think in terms of sets and joins - ie: joining to your data set on

```
on data.age between range.minage and range.maxage
```

and using `group by` and `count` to find your results

In general, it is a bad idea to store age in your dataset. It will never be accurate and will steadily decay.