# TSQL Count appearance Group by values in other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to group some data to show in a graph but... it is too difficult for me :-(

In one table I have  customers info, among that, Name, Kgs and yearly turnover

```
CustomerA               8       415.86
CustomerB          145846      6815.80
..............
CustomerZC          25160     25690.30
```

and I need to COUNT customers that has bought less than 50 Kgs, how many bought from 51 to 100, from 100 to 1.000, from 1000 to 30.000 and so on
but since groups limit are not similar, the boundaries of each range are stored in another table and looks like

```
Group0      0-50
Group1     51-100
Group2    101-1000
.....
Group15  1000001-5000000
Group16  5000001-9999999999
```

but I can modify it if it can helps

My Target is to have result like this:

```
0-50          14217
51-100         6425
101-1000        841
....
1000001-5000000  43
```

Now I achieve this result making 15 different queries but I would like to make an global algorithm that can adapt to a variable number of groups

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's got about a million duplicates

Comment: can suggest a duplicate.. since I've not been able to find any..
perhaps I used the wrong keywords
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351876/169012) is similar, take a look at the second option that joins to a range table.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
select   r.boundary_name, coalesce(count(*), 0) as cnt
from     ranges r
left join customers c
on       c.kgs between r.low_range and r.high_range
group by r.boundary_name;
```

Naturally you'd need to tweak the join if you're looking for exclusive ranges vs. inclusive, and the ranges table will need a low and high bound column.

Comment: Hi, Works perfectly and is much more simple than I could ever thought.. I'll try to learn something from this.
Concerning the similar question.. actually I've not found it, but did not use a table for ranges and seems much more complicated..
Anyway, thanks a lot!